# creating bold text/cells with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

im trying to bold text but im failing to do so, for a reason i realy dont know, i have followed steps in the documentation of PHPExcel, but to no result, here is my code:

```
    require_once './classes/PHPExcel.php';
    Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    include('./classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:k1');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(25);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(18);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(18);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(18);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(40);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setcellValue('A25', "Answer")
    ->setcellValue('B25', "Surname")
    ->setcellValue('C25', "Name")
    ->setcellValue('D25', "Contact Number")
    ->setcellValue('E25', "Comment");

    //some stuff in between...
    //problem starts here...

    $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
    $objRichText->createText('This invoice is ');

    $objPayable = $objRichText->createTextRun('payable within thirty days after the end        of the month');
    $objPayable->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setItalic(true);
    $objPayable->getFont()->setColor( new PHPExcel_Style_Color( PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_DARKGREEN ) );

    $objRichText->createText(', unless specified otherwise on the invoice.');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A18')->setValue($objRichText);
```

Comment: Looks good when I run it for Excel5, Excel2007 and HTML writers: what Writer are you using?

Comment: What version of PHPExcel then? I've simply cut and pasted your code directly from your question... and is it writing anything to the cell? are you getting any warnings from Excel when you read the file that's created?

Comment: version 1.7.2, no warnings, and yes its writing to the cell, but no styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from release 1.7.2 to a more recent version that includes support for Rich Text in the Excel5 writer might help... version 1.7.2 is nearly 3-years old. 1.7.7 is the current production release, with 1.7.8 already overdue but available on github.

This was Work item #8916 on the Issues list, and support was added in production release 1.7.7