# PHPExcel Make first row bold

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to make cells in first row are bold.

This is the method I have created for that purpose.

```
function ExportToExcel($tittles,$excel_name)
 {
  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $objRichText = new PHPExcel_RichText();
  // Set properties
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("SAMPLE1");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("SAMPLE1");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("SAMPLE1");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("SAMPLE1");
  $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("SAMPLE1");


  // Add some data
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  $letters = range('A','Z');
  $count =0;
  $cell_name="";
  foreach($tittles as $tittle)
  {
   $cell_name = $letters[$count]."1";
   $count++;
   $value = $tittle;
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($cell_name, $value);
   // Make bold cells
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell_name)->getFont()->setBold(true);
  }
  // Save Excel 2007 file
  $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
  //$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
  $objWriter->save($excel_name.".xlsx");
 }
```

The problem is in output excel file the cells are not bold.

Comment: is it making all rows bold or not any?

Comment: have you tried echoing $cell_name? is it giving the correct cellname?

Comment: @BhavikShah cell names are correct.

Comment: dude, try to increase the font-size. Give it a shot. Not sure.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797280/creating-bold-text-cells-with-phpexcel?rq=1). This might help you.

Answer (score 144):

Try this for range of cells:

```
$from = "A1"; // or any value
$to = "B5"; // or any value
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("$from:$to")->getFont()->setBold( true );
```

or single cell

```
$cell_name = "A1";
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle( $cell_name )->getFont()->setBold( true );
```

Comment: No, just A1 or A1:B1 for the 2 cells

Answer (score 51):

Try this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Answer (score 34):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

That way you get the complete first row

Comment: how to set my third row bold?

Comment: Worked for me - 2:2 set whole second row as bold. Also getStyle(2) worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me.. I had to set specific from/to coordinates :-(

Comment: doesn't work the complete row selection in this way

Answer (score 19):

Assuming headers are on the first row of the sheet starting at A1, and you know how many of them there are, this was my solution:

```
$header = array(
    'Header 1',
    'Header 2'
);

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcelSheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
$objPHPExcelSheet->fromArray($header, NULL);
$first_letter = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(0);
$last_letter = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(count($header)-1);
$header_range = "{$first_letter}1:{$last_letter}1";
$objPHPExcelSheet->getStyle($header_range)->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Answer (score 18):

Use this:

```
$sheet->getStyle('A1:'.$sheet->getHighestColumn().'1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Answer (score 10):

These are some tips to make your cells `Bold`, `Big font`, `Italic`

Let's say  I have columns from `A` to `L`

`A1` - is your starting cell

`L1` - is your last cell

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:L1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:L1')->getFont()->setSize(16);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:L1')->getFont()->setItalic(true);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:".$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()."1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

I found this to be a working solution, you can replace the two instances of `1` with the row number. The `HighestDataColumn` function returns for example C or Z, it gives you the last/highest column that's in the sheet containing any data. There is also `getHighestColumn()`, that one would include cells that are empty but have styling or are part of other functionality.

Answer (score 2):

This iterates through a **variable number of columns** of a particular row, which in this case is the 1st row:

```
$rownumber = 1;
$row = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator($rownumber)->current();

$cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);

foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->setBold(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to make bold headers:

```
$row = 1;
foreach($tittles as $index => $tittle) {
    $worksheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($index + 1, $row)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($index + 1, $row, $tittle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                                 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
                                 ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                                 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                                 ->setCategory("Test result file");
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'No');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Job ID');
    $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Job completed Date');
    $sheet->setCellValue('D1', 'Job Archived Date');
    $styleArray = array(
        'font' => array(
        'bold' => true
        )
    );
    $sheet->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $sheet->getStyle('B1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $sheet->getStyle('C1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $sheet->getStyle('D1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $sheet->getPageSetup()->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(1, 1);
```

This is give me output like below link.(https://www.screencast.com/t/ZkKFHbDq1le)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle(1)->getFont()->setBold(true);
```