# Store specific row count with array_push

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel, array-push

I'm trying to store a count of specific array items so that I know which row to style in laravel excel

What I would like to do is increase my iterator `$rowCount` any time I do an array_push, but any time I specifically process an array_push for `$groupItem`, I want to store the count in `$boldRows` that way I can apply styling to only those rows.

```
$allgroupResult= array();

$rowCount = 2; //since I have a sticky header in the excel file I start the count at 2
$boldRows = array();

foreach($prices->groups as $group){ 
    $groupItem = array(); 
    $groupItem["category_code"] = $group->category_code;
    $groupItem["category_name"] = $group->category_name; 
    $groupItem["category_description"] = $group->category_description;

    array_push($allgroupResult, $groupItem);    

    foreach($group->skus as $sku){
        $skuItem = array(); 
        $skuItem["identifier"] = $sku->info->identifier;

        array_push($allgroupResult, $skuItem);    
    }
}
```

category one with 3 products (total of 4 rows) and category two with 2 products (total of 3 rows), would give me 7 total rows starting at row 2. So my expected result with this would be that `$boldRows` would then contain 2 and 6 for the category rows (because my count starts at 2  then processes 3 products so the next category row is at 6)

How can I properly achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that you just needed to increment the rowcount each time you push a new element to the array and keep track of the rows you want to be in bold...

```
$rowCount = 2; //since I have a sticky header in the excel file I start the count at 2
$boldRows = array();

foreach($prices->groups as $group){ 
    $groupItem = array(); 
    $groupItem["category_code"] = $group->category_code;
    $groupItem["category_name"] = $group->category_name; 
    $groupItem["category_description"] = $group->category_description;

    array_push($allgroupResult, $groupItem); 
    array_push($boldRows, $rowCount++);   // Store count & increment

    foreach($group->skus as $sku){
        $skuItem = array(); 
        $skuItem["identifier"] = $sku->info->identifier;

        array_push($allgroupResult, $skuItem);
        $rowCount++;    // Just increment count
    }
}
```

You may need to adjust the `$rowCount` depending on how the rows match the arrays - arrays are 0 based and I don't know how the rows will be based.

Based on [PHPExcel Make first row bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746332/phpexcel-make-first-row-bold) and the row number excel row conversion from [Convert A to 1 B to 2 ... Z to 26 and then AA to 27 AB to 28 (column indexes to column references in Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951517/convert-a-to-1-b-to-2-z-to-26-and-then-aa-to-27-ab-to-28-column-indexes-to) (modified for PHP), you can then use something like ...

```
foreach ( $boldRows as $row )   {
    $cell_name = excelColumnFromNumber($row)."1";
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle( $cell_name )->getFont()->setBold( true );
}

function excelColumnFromNumber($column)
{
    $columnString = "";
    while ($column > 0)
    {
        $currentLetterNumber = ($column - 1) % 26;
        $columnString = chr($currentLetterNumber + 65) . $columnString;
        $column = ($column - ($currentLetterNumber + 1)) / 26;
    }
    return $columnString;
}
```

Comment: I think that makes sense. Do you know the syntax of how I could then use the $boldRows array to bold the font with  laravel excel/PHPExcel

Comment: Added some new code which may do the bold bits - you just need to see if the rows match up.

Comment: Thank you, so would I call those within my $sheet ?